# Send variable javascript to controller laravel to update vueJS

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I´m traying send data from my modal to one controller for update data, but i don´t know how declare my variable and how i must send this variable...

my actual code is:

**vuejs**

```
<script>

export default {

    data() {
        return {
            datosUsuario: [],
            isOpen: false,
            selectedItem: {},
            nombreUsuario: nombreUsuario,
        };

    },
    created: function () {
        this.cargar();
    },
    methods: {
        cargar: function () {
            let url = "/getDatosPersonales";
            axios
                .get(url)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.datosUsuario = response.data;
                })
                .catch((error) => console.error(error));
        },
        actualizar: function(){
            let nombreUsuario = document.getElementById('nombre');
            let url = "/actualizarDatos";
            axios
                .post(url)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log(nombreUsuario);
                })
                .catch((error) => console.error(error))
        },
        setSelectedItem(item) {
            this.selectedItem = item;
        }
    },
};
```

when i do click in my button this call a function "actualizar"

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Guardar" @click="actualizar">
```

i was check that if i do click in button go to my controller and it´s ok, but now i need to pass data in request for update, and i don´t know .

thanks so much for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get solve my problem, it´s very easy. share my solution

```
actualizar: function(){
            let url = "/actualizarDatos";
            axios
                .post(url, {
                    idUsuario: this.datosUsuario.id,
                    nombreUsuario: this.datosUsuario.nombre,
                    email: this.datosUsuario.email,
                    direccion: this.datosUsuario.direccion,
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                    
                })
                .catch((error) => console.error(error))
        },
```